# permutations with restrictions on python

Tags: python, loops, permutation

I want to create all possible sequence of numbers with 10 digits by using numbers 0 to 9 . Each digit should be used only once like:

`5 2 8 7 3 0 6 1 9 4` and `5 0 6 2 7 8 3 1 9 4`.

So there are P(10,10) = 3 628 800 possible combinations out there. However there are three rules about the ordering of elements:

`2 > 8 > 3 > 9 > 4` (rule 1) and `5 > 9 > 4` (rule 2) and `2 > 8 > 1` (rule 3). Here `>` sign means left operand should be on a higher significance digit (meaning closer to the left). Unspecified numbers in the rules which are `0 6 7` could be used anywhere on the combination.

So I have this idea of having a list of all possible combinations and then applying rules one by one and discard the sequences that do not follow. However, after some thoughts, found out that I can further assess the precise position for some digits, lets say `2`. Looking at `2,8,3,9,4` (rule 1), there should be at least 4 elements on the rightside of `2`--> `(8,3,9,4)`. This makes `2` could be assigned to digits `D(1,2,3,4,5,6)` (1 is MSB and 10 is LSB). Further investigating `2,8,1` (rule 3) `1` should also be on the right side of `2` that makes `2` could be assigned to `D(1,2,3,4,5)`. There are no further simplifications I figured out, and that's it I guess.

So what kind of approach might work here? I don't know even if the brute-force approach I suggest is feasible yet have to check it but I'm looking for a neater pythonic way to implement this.

P.S. An idea is that we can split rules like

`(2>8),(2>3),(2>9),(2>4)`

`(8>3),(8>9),(8>4)`

`(3>9),(3>4)`

`(9>4)` for rule 1. But it still looks like a brute-force to me.

Comment: Is there a rule for 0 not to be the first digit?

Comment: Definitely not. Since they are not numbers but integers.

Comment: Alright, then the answers provided work (let us know if you aren't happy w them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy, you can use `itertools.permutations()`, and as it generates tuples, we check to see each tuple meets the rules:

```
from itertools import permutations

for t in permutations(range(10), 10):
    if t.index(2) < t.index(8) < t.index(3) < t.index(9) < t.index(4) and t.index(5) < t.index(9) < t.index(4) and t.index(2) < t.index(8) < t.index(1):
        print(t)
```

Comment: Is `permutations(range(10),10)` generated and then looped through, or it is generated as the loop progresses?

Comment: It is generated as the loop progresses.

Comment: This works and I'm shocked after figuring out saving 3.6 m elements into a list only takes mere seconds.

Answer (score -1):

For the brute force method & for rule1 and rule2, you can do this:

```
import itertools
allpermutations = list(itertools.permutations([x for x in range(10)]))

def rule1(seq):
    return seq.index(2) < seq.index(8) and seq.index(8) < seq.index(3) and seq.index(3) < seq.index(9) and seq.index(9) < seq.index(4)

def rule2(seq):
    return seq.index(5) < seq.index(9) and seq.index(9) < seq.index(4)

result = [eachsequence for eachsequence in allpermutations if rule1(eachsequence) and rule2(eachsequence)]
```

(Similarly for rule3.)

For `itertools` usage, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/104436/8565438), for the `.index()` method, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/176921/8565438).

Comment: This is not efficient. It writes *all* possible permutations into memory, when don't need a good fraction of them.